# I want to select data from database what is the error in my code ,

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

```
<center>
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <th><a href="phpfirstpjroject.php">Add data here</a></th>
    <th> Name</th>
    <th>City_Name</th>
    <th colspan="2">Operation</th>
</tr>
<?php
include_once'dbconfiguration.php';
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM usertable";
$result_set=$con->query($sql_query);
while($row=$result_set->fetch_assoc()) {
 ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
 <td align="center"><a href="javascript:edt_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')"> 
 <img src="b_edit.png" align="EDIT" /></a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="javascript:delete_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ? 
   >')"><img src="b_drop.png" align="DELETE" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
  }
  ?>   
  }
  ?>
  </table>
  </center>
```

HERE IS THE OUT PUT 
Add data here   Name    City_Name   Operation

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpread.php on line 26

Comment: if you do `var_dump( $result_set );` do you get a meaningful result displayed?

Comment: @RamRaider No, i am not get any result but show me another error undefined variable result_set

Comment: has the database connection script been included correctly - ie: is the db available? The db connection is definitely called `$con`?

Comment: yes the database is available.

Comment: ok - so if you run that exact same query in your `mysql client` program or cmd line does it run correctly?

Comment: yes it is run correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use fetch_assoc you should access tho the values using  the related column name

```
   while($row=$result_set->fetch_array()) {
     ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['my_col1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['my_col2']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['my_col3']; ?></td>
        ...................
```

if you want access by position you should use fetch_array()

```
$result_set=$con->query($sql_query);
    while($row=$result_set->fetch_array()) {
     ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
        .......
```

rememamber tha the index  start form 0 in the way you are using you are accessing to the column in position  1,2,3  (skipping the first  at position zero